# An error occurred while retrieving token. FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I'm trying to integrate FCM to my react (with typescript) application. I'm trying to fetch the FCM tokens, but I keep getting this error :

> An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

Here is my code :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging,getToken   } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const fcmMessaging = getMessaging();
getToken(fcmMessaging, { vapidKey: 'xcv' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    console.log(currentToken,"FCM token")
  } else {

    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
  }
}).catch((err:any) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});
```

Comment: Have you check this github post about [FCM Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. The operation is insecure. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/229)?

Answer (score 0):

just replace this import { getMessaging} from 'firebase/messaging';
with this import { getMessaging} from 'firebase/messaging/sw';